# How to access the second level foreign key using Supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js, supabase-realtime

I have `countries` tables and `cities` tables with a `country` field that refers to `countries` tables as a relation, and finally `jobs` table that has a `city` field that refers to the `cities` table .. now when I query on jobs. I can only access `job.city` and never being able to get `job.city.country` .. here is my code:

```
  async function fetchJobs() {
    const { data: fetchedJobs } = await supabaseInstance().from("jobs").select("*,cities!inner(*,countries!inner(id))").order('created_at', { ascending: false });
    setJobs(fetchedJobs)
  }
```

am pretty sure I have something wrong in the `select` query but I have been looking for the right one for ages and can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming related cities and countries will always be present, you don't need `!inner` keyword.

```js
    const { data: fetchedJobs } = await supabaseInstance().from("jobs").select("*,cities(*,countries(id))").order('created_at', { ascending: false });
```